# Loop redirect when ping my gateway

Tags: router, ping

I have a router with WAN and LAN setup and act as DHCP server/gateway on my local LAN. The IP address is `192.168.1.1`.

Today, I was hit by an internet failure and I checked the ping and get this weird ping result. Why the router continues to look for himself?

```
From 192.168.1.88: icmp_seq=6 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.1.1)
From 192.168.1.88: icmp_seq=6 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.1.1)
...........
```

Comment: What IP address were you pinging? And is 192.168.1.88 the IP address of the machine you were pinging from?

Comment: Yes. 192.168.1.88 is my machine within the LAN. 192.168.1.1 is the gateway/DNS of this LAN. I connect to the gateway through APs (192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.7), all those APs could be pinged through.

Comment: It sounds like you have a router that's trying to route between hosts inside the same subnet. That won't usually work correctly. Are the APs using WDS?

Comment: Yes. All the APs are connected by one switches with DHCP turned off. I have zeroed in the problem on to one Virtual Machine on my local computer. Once I set the VM to 'bridge' the LAN my host machine is on, the looping happens.  Is there any information I could provide to detect the exact causes?

Answer (score 5):

[ICMP Redirects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_Redirect_Message)  are sent by a router when there is a more direct route from the client to the destination. This implies that your client is not actually using 192.168.1.1 as its default route, but rather is using 192.168.1.88 -- what does the routing table on the source look like?

Your setup is not very clear from your question though: which machine (and IP) are you pinging from, what IP are you pinging, and what is the network path between the source and the destination (routers, switches, APs, virtual machine hosts, etc.).